# Can nw addon be built with _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=1 for debug mode? (Windows)

Tags: chromium, nwjs, node-addon-api

##### Original questin: Is there any way to get what macros nw-gyp add to the build project by default?

I'm developing a nw addon and I've tried to link a custom static lib to .node DLL. However I found nw-gyp will add _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0 by default (It always appends to the addon project to override custom defines), which will affect the actual structure size for STL types (e.g. std::string).

So is there a way to get such macros node gyp added by default, or is there an easy way to make compiler's (maybe the whole toolchain, link tool etc.) configuration for both static lib and nw build project the same?

Now I've add _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0 to my lib and make it MT(D), and It seems to work fine, but I'm not sure if this is the right way. (Some other compiler settings may not cause compilation error but can crash in runtime)

##### Edit: Share some analysis to make my origin question clearer.

> All current question is on Windows platform.

The _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0 is added even when I build nw addon in **debug mode** (with --debug), and this may be affected by the nw headers downloaded by nw-gyp. For example, headers download from http://node-webkit.s3.amazonaws.com/v0.49.2/nw-headers-v0.49.2.tar.gz , you will find `'defines': [ 'DEBUG', '_DEBUG', 'V8_ENABLE_CHECKS', '_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0' ]` in common.gypi at line 288 in Debug_Base config section, and this is most likely inherit from https://github.com/nwjs/chromium.src (I guess here https://github.com/nwjs/chromium.src/blob/nw60/build/config/BUILD.gn#L130). So can it be concluded that Chrome add these defines for debug mode on purpose?

**What is the problem `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0` in debug for me?**  Well, it affects the size for many STL classes (std::string, std::vector and etc.). So all debug lib that need to be linked to nw addon should be compiled with `'_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0'`, otherwise compilation error will occur for static libs and runtime pointer problem crash (struct offset mismatch) for dynamic libs (of course it is not a good practice to use STL in dynamic lib headers, but if you can assume the toolchain same it will still work fine). But this is really hard for me when it comes to third-party binaries, I've got no sources for most of them, so I can't give a debug static lib with `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0` on. This is really frustrating when I need to debug the addon with lldb or VS, since all variables are optimized and you cannot debug their values.

**Can I force `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=1` for debug mode?** As mentioned in origin question, it cannot be done normally like answer from [@mmomtchev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70805996/12202748). A hack way to do is to add `"/D _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=1"` to `configurations->Debug->msvs_settings->VCLinkerTool->AdditionalOptions` in gyp file for addon, this will append `/D _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=1` to the end of the compile command which override the former defination. **But I'm not sure if this is a good workaround!** I've checked v8 header files and have found some  classes with std::string and std::vector members. I think force _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING will cause some problem if you use these classes, but for other classes it is safe (I've tested many cases, normal classes like v8::value v8::function work well). **And it is not safe when cooperating with other addons.** Let's assume one debug addon A and another release addon B need to communicate with each other, they agree on one C++ struct for data exchange. A common way is to let A to wrap a C++ struct instance to a JS object for user. and let user pass the JS object to B by calling methods provided by B (the JS object is one of the arguments), and then B unwrap the JS object from arguments and get the pointer of the C++ struct instance. All looks fine, but what if the C++ struct has std::string member? The sizes of same C++ struct for A and B are not the same. so B will crash when trying to access the member with type of std::string or std::vector. This is not an issue if _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0 is set for debug mode since _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING is always disabled for release, and I guess that's why nw addon can work with mixed production mode(debug an release) addons in common cases.

So my final question is: **If it is not a good way to force `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=1` for debug and I don't have source code for many external compiled lib binaries, does it mean I've no way to build a nw addon in debug mode?** Athother possible way is to wrapper those libs with C style API and compile them to dynamic libs, but this is really huge work for me and is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0` is defined by default on all `Release` builds.

If you need to add macros, you need to add this section to the root of your gyp:

`'defines': [ '_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0' ]`

Comment: Yes, I understand better your question now. I don't think you have any choice short of recompiling nw. Normally, there is a linker check that prevents you from linking code that does not have matching `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` - so you will get a linker error instead of a runtime crash.